# How to overwrite a value from input with type="date" that comes from a v-model in vuejs?

Tags: html, vue.js

That is my problem, the dates comes with that format "`9999-99-99 00:00:00`", but i want to set it to "`9999-99-99`". But it came in an array, and has a lot fields. My question is, how to overwrite the value using the vuejs?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    fields: [{
        "id": 1,
        "date": "2019-02-05",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "2018-12-01 00:00:00",

      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "date": "2017-02-05 00:00:00",

      }
    ]
  }),
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div v-for="field in fields" :key="field.id">
      <input v-model="field.date" type="date">
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

I tried to use computed method, but it just call this when i set the value manually. Then i tried this and it works. But,
is this an efficient way to do this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    formatValue( key){
      this.fields[key].date = this.fields[key].date.split(" ")[0];
    }
  },
  
  data: () => ({
     fields: 
     [  
       {  
          "id":3958,
          "date":"2019-02-05",
       },
       {  
          "id":3959,
          "date":"2018-12-01 00:00:00",

       },
        {  
          "id":3960,
          "date":"2017-02-05 00:00:00",

       }
    ]
  }),
  
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div v-for="(value, key) of fields" :key="key">
      <input v-model="fields[key].date" type="date" >{{value.date}} {{formatValue(key)}}
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

The second method runs twice, because he had to re-render, so it's not a good idea.

Comment: why you don't like a `"2018-12-01 00:00:00"`-format?

Comment: The input type="date" doesn't understand this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/we8o3p7r/2/

```
function makeCorrectDate(str) {
    return new Date(str).toISOString().split('T')[0]
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    fields: [{
        "id": 1,
        "date": makeCorrectDate("2019-02-05"),
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "date": makeCorrectDate("2018-12-01 00:00:00"),

      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "date": makeCorrectDate("2017-02-05 00:00:00"),
      }
    ]
  }),
});
```

---

Another way to do it:

```
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div v-for="field in fields" :key="field.id">
      <input
        :value="makeCorrectDate(field.date)"
        @input="field.date = $event.target.value"
        type="date"
      />
      <div>{{ field.date }}</div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: I receive the fields from a request, how do i apply this function in execution time? I will have to iterate the array one by one and apply? I don't think its a good idea :(

Comment: I think that working with data in proper format - is a very good idea :)
But if you want a workaroud - https://jsfiddle.net/6ycnt8xv/

Comment: That's gave me a ideia, using a hidden field to do this split, but your ideia is more graceful.
 <input v-model="field.date">
 <input :value="field.date = new Date(field.date).toISOString().split('T')[0]" type="hidden">

Answer (score 1):

I would use a filter with [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    fields: [{
        "id": 1,
        "date": "2019-02-05"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "2018-12-01 00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "date": "2017-02-05 00:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }),

  filters: {
    formatDate(val) {
      return moment(val).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(value, key) in fields" :key="key">
    <input v-model="fields[key].date" type="date" /> {{value.date | formatDate}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: moment.js is very BIG ;(